# angularjs change ng-repeat nested value from parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to change the "taskAssembly.qnt" value in the nested ng-repeat when I change the number from the "pens" or "Tow"

see this plunker.  http://plnkr.co/edit/rKnup0IIPRYvh8JLHXbD?p=preview

see my data:

```
 { "client": "client1","takeoff": [
{
  "taskName": "ToW",
  "taskQnt": 2300,
  "taskAssembly": [
    {
      "qnt": "",
      "product": "spray",
      "labour": 12,
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "qnt": "",
      "product": "strips",
      "labour": 10,
      "name": "John"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want when i change takeOff.taskQnt the taskAssembly.qnt in the ng-repeat to change

This function does not work.

```
$scope.adjustTaskQnt = function (items) {

var test = 0;
for (var i in items) {
  items[i].qnt == $scope.takeOff.taskQnt
   }

return $scope.taskAssembly.qnt;
```

};

any idea how this can be done?

Comment: do you want same taskQnt value for all taskAssembly.qnt according to ToW and Pens

Comment: yes.  the idea is the to change the qnt in the "pens" (or the "tow")  and change each one of the nested rows

Comment: this is what u expect?  http://plnkr.co/edit/wEJwiQFiDta3Sy5ZiyDL?p=preview

Comment: just about.  the "pens" to change only the "pens" nested rows and the "tow" only the "tow" rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying the adjustTaksQnt function and the  template as follows.

```
$scope.adjustTaskQnt = function($index) {
   angular.forEach($scope.estimate.takeoff[$index].taskAssembly, function(value, key) {
      value.qnt = $scope.estimate.takeoff[$index].taskQnt;
   });
};
```

HTML Template

```
<input type="text" class="qnt" ng-model="takeOff.taskQnt" ng-change="adjustTaskQnt( $index )">
```

Answer (score 0):

this will also works, just modify your function

```
$scope.adjustTaskQnt = function (items) {
    //  var test = 0;
    //for (var i in items) {
    // items[i].qnt == $scope.takeOff.taskQnt;
    //}
    for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){

        if(items[i].taskName=="ToW"){
            for(j=0;j<items[i].taskAssembly.length;j++){
                items[i].taskAssembly[j].qnt=items[i].taskQnt;
            }
        }
        else if(items[i].taskName=="Pens"){
            for(j=0;j<items[i].taskAssembly.length;j++){
                items[i].taskAssembly[j].qnt=items[i].taskQnt;
            }
        }
    }
    return $scope.taskAssembly.qnt;
  };
```

Comment: this would require you to have a condition for every taskName, which would be unfeasible for large datasets

Comment: @sparticus_37 thanks for your suggestion, i was not aware about this things :)